# Concat 2 arrays inside object based on object key/value

Tags: json, jq

I have multiple json objects which could be less when i merge the arrays if a object key matches the same value as the next json object. I'm trying to accomplish this with jq.

I think i have to use group_by(.name) first to group matching keys. I'm also using slurp to first wrap all objects into one big array.

I don't have anything working for now.

given:

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "list": [ "a1", "a2" ]
}
{
    "name": "a",
    "list": [ "a3", "a4" ]
}
{
    "name": "b",
    "list": [ "b1", "b2" ]
}
```

should result in:

```
{
    "name": "a",
    "list": [ "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4" ]
}
{
    "name": "b",
    "list": [ "b1", "b2" ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `reduce` like this:

```
$ jq -c -n 'reduce inputs as $p ({}; .[$p.name] |= { name : $p.name, list : (.list + $p.list) }) | .[]' file
{"name":"a","list":["a1","a2","a3","a4"]}
{"name":"b","list":["b1","b2"]}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, that seems to work! not sure why the null-input was required.

Comment: @krstfvndm It lets you use `inputs`. This is a quick workaround though, there might be better solutions

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, just changed your example to match my real dataset, and its flawless, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple and efficient solution that uses a common "aggregate by" technique:

```
reduce inputs as $kv ({}; .[$kv.name] += $kv.list)
| keys_unsorted[] as $k
| {name: $k, list: .[$k]}
```

Since `inputs` has been used here, the -n command-line option of jq should be specified.